Code reads from an XML file but can't find anything
I want to read an XML file and write the information to a MySQL database (localhost).
The table:
CREATE TABLE ClimateMonitoring (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    label VARCHAR(255),
    value_type INT,
    offset FLOAT,
    gain FLOAT,
    precision_level INT,
    value VARCHAR(255),
    unit VARCHAR(50),
    sensor_date DATETIME,
    insert_date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);


The code:
from lxml import etree
import mysql.connector

def parse_and_insert_to_mysql(file_path, db_config):
    conn = None
    cursor = None
    data_found = False
    try:
        # Parse the XML file using lxml
        print("Parsing XML file using lxml...")
        tree = etree.parse(file_path)
        root = tree.getroot()
        print("XML file parsed successfully.")

        # Print the root tag to verify successful parsing
        print(f"Root tag: {root.tag}")

        # Define the namespace
        namespace = {'icom': 'something'}

        # Connect to the MySQL database
        print("Connecting to MySQL database...")
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(**db_config)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        print("Connected to MySQL database.")

        # Extract data and insert into the database
        for item in root.findall('icom:Item', namespaces=namespace):
            data_found = True  # Set flag to true if at least one item is found
            item_id = item.attrib['id']
            name = item.attrib['name']
            label = item.find('icom:Label', namespaces=namespace).text
            value_element = item.find('icom:Value', namespaces=namespace)
            value_type = value_element.attrib['valueType']
            offset = value_element.attrib['offset']
            gain = value_element.attrib['gain']
            precision_level = value_element.attrib['precision']
            value = value_element.text
            unit = item.find('icom:Unit', namespaces=namespace).text if item.find('icom:Unit', namespaces=namespace) is not None else ''
            sensor_date = '2024-10-05 00:00:00'

            # Debugging: Print each value to verify correctness
            print(f"Preparing to insert: id={item_id}, name={name}, label={label}, value_type={value_type}, offset={offset}, gain={gain}, precision_level={precision_level}, value={value}, unit={unit}, sensor_date={sensor_date}")

            insert_query = (
                "INSERT INTO ClimateMonitoring (id, name, label, value_type, offset, gain, precision_level, value, unit, sensor_date) "
                "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
            )
            try:
                cursor.execute(insert_query, (item_id, name, label, value_type, offset, gain, precision_level, value, unit, sensor_date))
                print(f"Inserted row with id={item_id}")
            except mysql.connector.Error as e:
                print(f"Failed to insert row with id={item_id}: {e}")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Unexpected error when inserting row with id={item_id}: {e}")

        # Check if no data was found
        if not data_found:
            raise ValueError("No insertable data found in the XML file.")

        # Commit the transaction
        print("Committing transaction...")
        conn.commit()
        print("Transaction committed successfully.")

    except etree.XMLSyntaxError as e:
        print(f"Error parsing the XML file: {e}")
    except mysql.connector.Error as e:
        print(f"Error with MySQL database: {e}")
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
    finally:
        # Close the database connection
        if cursor:
            cursor.close()
        if conn:
            conn.close()
        print("Database connection closed.")

# Path to your XML file
file_path = r"path"

# MySQL database configuration
db_config = {
    'user': 'root',
    'password': 'password',  # The password you set during installation
    'host': 'localhost',     # Localhost
    'database': 'climate'  # The database you created
}

parse_and_insert_to_mysql(file_path, db_config)

XML file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/simon.xsl" ?>
<icom:something schemaVersion="1.00" appVersion="1" xmlns:icom="a1234">
<Item id="354" name="SinglState">
<Label>Unit Status</Label>
<Value valueType="262144" offset="0.000" gain="1.000" precision="0">Unit On</Value>
<Unit></Unit>
</Item>
<Item id="361" name="LocTemp">
<Label>Return Air Temperature</Label>
<Value valueType="393216" offset="0.000" gain="1.000" precision="1">22.1</Value>
<Unit>&#176;C</Unit>
</Item>
<Item id="379" name="Std. Sensor Humidity">
<Label>Return Air Humidity</Label>
<Value valueType="393216" offset="0.000" gain="1.000" precision="1">35.1</Value>
<Unit>%rH</Unit>
</Item>
<Item id="380" name="Supply Air Temperature">
<Label>Supply Air Temperature</Label>
<Value valueType="393216" offset="0.000" gain="1.000" precision="1">---</Value>
<Unit></Unit>
</Item>
<Item id="356" name="Actual Temperature Setpoint">
<Label>Return Air Temperature Setpoint</Label>
<Value valueType="393216" offset="0.000" gain="1.000" precision="1">21.5</Value>
<Unit>&#176;C</Unit>
</Item>
<Item id="547" name="HuSetActDi">
<Label>Return Air Humidity Setpoint</Label>
<Value valueType="393216" offset="0.000" gain="1.000" precision="0">No</Value>
<Unit></Unit>
</Item>
<Item id="401" name="Supply Setpoint">
<Label>Supply Air Temperature Setpoint</Label>
<Value valueType="393216" offset="0.000" gain="1.000" precision="1">5.0</Value>
<Unit>&#176;C</Unit>
</Item>
<Item id="1110" name="Show_Fan">
<Label>Fan Status</Label>
<Value valueType="0" offset="0.000" gain="1.000" precision="0">On</Value>
<Unit></Unit>
</Item>
<Item id="1111" name="Show_Cool">
<Label>Cooling Status</Label>
<Value valueType="0" offset="0.000" gain="1.000" precision="0">On</Value>
<Unit></Unit>
</Item>
<Item id="1112" name="Show_FC">
<Label>Freecooling Status</Label>
<Value valueType="0" offset="0.000" gain="1.000" precision="0">Off</Value>
<Unit></Unit>
</Item>
<Item id="1114" name="Show_EHeat">
<Label>Electrical Heater Status</Label>
<Value valueType="0" offset="0.000" gain="1.000" precision="0">Off</Value>
<Unit></Unit>
</Item>
<Item id="1113" name="Show_HotW">
<Label>Hot Water Status</Label>
<Value valueType="0" offset="0.000" gain="1.000" precision="0">Off</Value>
<Unit></Unit>
</Item>
<Item id="1116" name="Show_Dehum">
<Label>Dehumdification Status</Label>
<Value valueType="0" offset="0.000" gain="1.000" precision="0">Off</Value>
<Unit></Unit>
</Item>
<Item id="1115" name="Show_Hum">
<Label>Humidifier Status</Label>
<Value valueType="0" offset="0.000" gain="1.000" precision="0">Off</Value>
<Unit></Unit>
</Item>
<Item id="1118" name="Show_Maint">
<Label>Maintenance Status</Label>
<Value valueType="0" offset="0.000" gain="1.000" precision="0">Off</Value>
<Unit></Unit>
</Item>
</icom:something>

The code connects to the database but gets no data from the XML file. I need it to fill the table with this info.

Please clarify if the problem is with reading the information from the xml file (in which case the question has nothing to do with mysql) or it cannot insert the read data from the xml (in which case the question has nothing to do with xml).

Again, it is not clear where you get stuck.

The XML has the namespace declaration xmlns:icom="a1234" so your Python namespace dictionary should be e.g. namespace = {'icom': 'a1234'}.
Furthermore most descendant elements are in no namespace so use e.g. item.find('Label', ..) instead of item.find('icom:Label', ..).
Full lxml/etree specific code:
for item in tree.findall('Item', namespaces=namespace):
    data_found = True  # Set flag to true if at least one item is found
    item_id = item.attrib['id']
    name = item.attrib['name']
    label = item.find('Label', namespaces=namespace).text
    value_element = item.find('Value', namespaces=namespace)
    value_type = value_element.attrib['valueType']
    offset = value_element.attrib['offset']
    gain = value_element.attrib['gain']
    precision_level = value_element.attrib['precision']
    value = value_element.text
    unit = item.find('Unit', namespaces=namespace).text if item.find('Unit',
                                                                          namespaces=namespace) is not None else ''
    sensor_date = '2024-10-05 00:00:00'

    # Debugging: Print each value to verify correctness
    print(
        f"Preparing to insert: id={item_id}, name={name}, label={label}, value_type={value_type}, offset={offset}, gain={gain}, precision_level={precision_level}, value={value}, unit={unit}, sensor_date={sensor_date}")

Spews out
Preparing to insert: id=354, name=SinglState, label=Unit Status, value_type=262144, offset=0.000, gain=1.000, precision_level=0, value=Unit On, unit=None, sensor_date=2024-10-05 00:00:00
Preparing to insert: id=361, name=LocTemp, label=Return Air Temperature, value_type=393216, offset=0.000, gain=1.000, precision_level=1, value=22.1, unit=°C, sensor_date=2024-10-05 00:00:00
Preparing to insert: id=379, name=Std. Sensor Humidity, label=Return Air Humidity, value_type=393216, offset=0.000, gain=1.000, precision_level=1, value=35.1, unit=%rH, sensor_date=2024-10-05 00:00:00
Preparing to insert: id=380, name=Supply Air Temperature, label=Supply Air Temperature, value_type=393216, offset=0.000, gain=1.000, precision_level=1, value=---, unit=None, sensor_date=2024-10-05 00:00:00
Preparing to insert: id=356, name=Actual Temperature Setpoint, label=Return Air Temperature Setpoint, value_type=393216, offset=0.000, gain=1.000, precision_level=1, value=21.5, unit=°C, sensor_date=2024-10-05 00:00:00
Preparing to insert: id=547, name=HuSetActDi, label=Return Air Humidity Setpoint, value_type=393216, offset=0.000, gain=1.000, precision_level=0, value=No, unit=None, sensor_date=2024-10-05 00:00:00
Preparing to insert: id=401, name=Supply Setpoint, label=Supply Air Temperature Setpoint, value_type=393216, offset=0.000, gain=1.000, precision_level=1, value=5.0, unit=°C, sensor_date=2024-10-05 00:00:00
Preparing to insert: id=1110, name=Show_Fan, label=Fan Status, value_type=0, offset=0.000, gain=1.000, precision_level=0, value=On, unit=None, sensor_date=2024-10-05 00:00:00
Preparing to insert: id=1111, name=Show_Cool, label=Cooling Status, value_type=0, offset=0.000, gain=1.000, precision_level=0, value=On, unit=None, sensor_date=2024-10-05 00:00:00
Preparing to insert: id=1112, name=Show_FC, label=Freecooling Status, value_type=0, offset=0.000, gain=1.000, precision_level=0, value=Off, unit=None, sensor_date=2024-10-05 00:00:00
Preparing to insert: id=1114, name=Show_EHeat, label=Electrical Heater Status, value_type=0, offset=0.000, gain=1.000, precision_level=0, value=Off, unit=None, sensor_date=2024-10-05 00:00:00
Preparing to insert: id=1113, name=Show_HotW, label=Hot Water Status, value_type=0, offset=0.000, gain=1.000, precision_level=0, value=Off, unit=None, sensor_date=2024-10-05 00:00:00
Preparing to insert: id=1116, name=Show_Dehum, label=Dehumdification Status, value_type=0, offset=0.000, gain=1.000, precision_level=0, value=Off, unit=None, sensor_date=2024-10-05 00:00:00
Preparing to insert: id=1115, name=Show_Hum, label=Humidifier Status, value_type=0, offset=0.000, gain=1.000, precision_level=0, value=Off, unit=None, sensor_date=2024-10-05 00:00:00
Preparing to insert: id=1118, name=Show_Maint, label=Maintenance Status, value_type=0, offset=0.000, gain=1.000, precision_level=0, value=Off, unit=None, sensor_date=2024-10-05 00:00:00

for me so for sure finds data in the XML

It didn't fix the problem.

@Trickfinger, see the edit, if you consistently avoid the prefix (the descendants are in no namespace) then you will find the data.

Update: Create a MariaDB database table and parse the XML with xml.etree.ElementTree. I used a portable MariaDB installation according this side. MariaDB is very similar like MySQL, so it should  work with no or less changes.
Why this update from pandas.to_sql() back to xml.etree.ElementTree? -> pd.to_sql() and sqlachemy changeed the database column type definition back to text!
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import mariadb
import sys

class Parse_xml:
    def __init__(self,item):
        self.id = self.item_attr(item, "id", "i")
        self.name = self.item_attr(item, "name", "s")
        self.label = self.tag_text(item, "Label")
        self.value = self.tag_text(item, "Value")
        self.v_valueType = self.item_attr(item, "valueType", "i")
        self.v_offset =  self.item_attr(item, "offset", "f")
        self.v_gain = self.item_attr(item, "gain", "f")
        self.v_precision = self.item_attr(item, "precision", "i")
        self.unit = self.tag_text(item, "Unit")
        print(self.id, self.name, self.label, self.v_valueType, self.v_offset, self.v_gain, self.v_precision, self.value, self.unit)

    def tag_text(self, elem_obj, tn):
        tex = []
        for e in elem_obj.iter():
            if e.tag == tn:
                tex.append(e.text)
        return tex[0]

    def item_attr(self, elem_obj, attr,  ty):
        d = []
        for a in elem_obj.iter():
            if a.get(attr) is not None:
                if ty == 'i':
                    d.append(int(a.get(attr)))
                if ty == 's':
                    d.append(a.get(attr))
                if ty == 'f':
                    d.append(float(a.get(attr)))
        return d[0]      
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        with mariadb.connect(
            host = "localhost",
            user = input("Enter username: "),
            password = input("Enter password: "),
            port = 3306,
            database = "climate",
        ) as conn:
            
            # Connect Message
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT version();")
            version = cur.fetchall()
            print("Connected to Database Version", version[0][0])
            
            sql = '''CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE climate.climate_monitoring (
                  id int(11) NOT NULL,
                  name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                  label varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                  values_type int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
                  v_offset float DEFAULT NULL,
                  v_gain float DEFAULT NULL,
                  v_precision int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
                  value varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                  unit varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
                  sensor_data DATETIME DEFAULT now(6),
                  insert_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
                  updated_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
                  PRIMARY KEY (id));'''
            cur.execute(sql)
            print("climate.climate_monitoring table created or replaced!")
            
            filename = "Climate_data.xml"
            for event, elem in ET.iterparse(filename, events = ('start',)):
                if elem.tag == 'Item':
                    data = Parse_xml(elem)
                    insert_data = (data.id, data.name, data.label, data.v_valueType, data.v_offset, data.v_gain, data.v_precision, data.value, data.unit)
                    cur = conn.cursor()
                    insert_sql = f"INSERT INTO climate_monitoring (id, name, label, values_type, v_offset, v_gain, v_precision, value, unit) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
                    cur.execute(insert_sql, insert_data)
                    conn.commit()
                    print("Data inserted")
                    elem.clear()
    
    except mariadb.Error as e:
        print(f"Error connecting to MariaDB Platform: {e}")
        sys.exit(1)

Output, in DBeaver:


Your XML is nested. So you must load it into 2 separate tables.
Upload your XML file to the directory where MySQL can import this file from (see session @@secure_file_priv setting). Then use:
CREATE TABLE ClimateMonitoring (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    Label VARCHAR(255),
    Unit VARCHAR(50),
    sensor_date DATETIME,
    insert_date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
LOAD XML INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/test.xml' 
INTO TABLE ClimateMonitoring 
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Item>'
SET insert_date = DEFAULT;

CREATE TABLE ClimateMonitoringValue (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    valueType INT,
    offset FLOAT,
    gain FLOAT,
    `precision` INT,
    Value VARCHAR(255),
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES ClimateMonitoring (id)
);
LOAD XML INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/test.xml' 
INTO TABLE ClimateMonitoringValue 
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Value>';

Pay attention - the columns names are case-sensitive.
Also you must assign the value to the autoutilized DATETIME column explicitly.
Now you can see and use the whole data using
SELECT *
FROM ClimateMonitoring
JOIN ClimateMonitoringValue USING (id);



Can't we do this while loading into a single table? Also, I plan to get xml files like this from an internet capable sensor and I want to write a code that regularly gets info and inserts to the table. Can you show me a roadmap on how to do it? Preferably in python.

@Trickfinger Can't we do this while loading into a single table? No, due to a bug in XML parser in MySQL. But you may load into 2 temptables then insert into one working table. I.e. final SELECT -> INSERT .. SELECT. Preferably in python. You have static SQL code which must be executed. I do not see the problem to do this in python code.
